# Certain web elements not showing on my Dell U3417W display but show fine on MacBook Pro display

Tags: display

I received a Dell U3417W from work while I work from home. I have a 2017 13" MacBook Pro running OS X Mojave. The display is connected to a CalDigit Thunderbolt dock via DisplayPort and from the dock to the computer using a Thunderbolt cable.

When I view web pages on the Dell display, things look "washed out" and in many cases, certain elements don't even show up. The perfect example is the Google home page. On my Dell display, there isn't a border around the search bar but on the MBP display there is.

I'd send a screenshot but even that shows differences depending on the display. And this happens on Firefox, Safari, and Chrome so I think it's a monitor issue, not browser-specific.

I've gone through the calibration wizard in the System Preferences but nothing changes. Any thoughts?

Here's a link to a [quick video showing the difference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cb198.jpg):

Comment: Sounds weird. But posting a video is actually not that helpful. Instead I would recommend taking two pictures with you smartphone (I assume) that you took the video with so they can be seen side by side.

Comment: Check the contrast setting on your monitor, it's likely too high.

Answer (score 1):

So a factory reset fixed the problem. I had messed with the contrast and that didn't seem to do anything. But all good now.